# Speed up Hibernate.find() query for batch process? (and reduce memory usage)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-orm

We have migrated from java 1.4 with a direct sql query against a database view to java 8, domain objects and orm persistence with hibernate.

My batch process must read 300,000 rows from the database, and it looks like this:

```
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

List<?> list = hibernateTemplate.find("from Widgets widgets where widget.status=?", status);
```

This however is extremely slow (9 minutes, compared to 30 seconds for a database query) and consumes a lot of memory.

I turned on hibernate `show_sql` and I can see that it spends a lot of time loading the domain objects from 3 different tables (Widget contains a Wobjet and a Wudget, let's say)

And since I don't need the whole `list` (I can do batch processing row-by-row), I wonder:

**Is there some sort of ResultSet in hibernate that is more memory efficient (and quicker) ?**

Incidentally, we are using spring batch, and the backing database is Oracle (although that can change).

It would be easier to get this working with the `HibernateTemplate`, if possible, since all the other operations in our `Dao` layer use the same template (though this is the first operation for batch processing large volumes of data).

Comment: Is it possible to keep using direct JDBC? Hibernate is not very suitable for batch processing, even when optimized to the fullest. Take it from someone who's been writing JPA/Spring Batches for the last couple of months...

Comment: Don't use the hibernate template, use Spring Batch for that. You don't want to read all objects at once and then process as that is, as you noticed, extremely slow... The same applies for writing don't wait until you have all rows but write every 50 or 100 rows (find a good trade off point) and after that clear the entity manager.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can you please guide me to how I should do the batch data reading via spring batch? And can I re-use the same domain objects (which are annotated for hibernate), or how should I write the database query otherwise?

Comment: Have a read through the Spring Batch documentation. The examples they give are fantastic. You'll need a `RowMapper` object to read your objects out of the database. Once you understand how Spring Batch works, you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks, I read the examples, and the key to my understanding here was that spring batch uses direct jdbc calls, and you use a read / process / write paradigm to direct the processing of the data in an understandable and efficient manner.